# Remove string after underscore

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
hbeu50271385_612_21
```

I'd like to remove the part of the string from the first underscore, so it ends up like this:

```
hbeu50271385
```

Not sure how I'd go about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
"hbeu50271385_612_21".replace(/_.*/, '')
```

Or

```
var str = "hbeu50271385_612_21";
str.substring(0, str.indexOf('_'))
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/gicetu/1/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish it by using split and grabbing the index [0] of the split string:

```
var result = str.split('_')[0];
```